# Getting table from Django POST request and displaying it in handsontable (read value in javascript)

Tags: python, django, post, handsontable

I have to render excel-like table with easy possibility to modify. I have web application in Django with mysql database. When I was searching for a solution I found Handsontable which looks as a good answer to my problem. But now i have a question:

How I can autofill handsontable after submitting a form? I have a form, where user can choose few options and generate tables with data. I have data in table of tables and I'm sending it using POST request.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TestForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        ### ACCESSING DATA FROM DATABASE
        ### CREATING 2D TABLE

        return render_to_response('rendered.html', {'form' : form, 'my_data' : my_data} )
```

After that I want to display my handsontable and render it with my data. It has to me did by Ajax? With dynamically builded handsontable or what?

I was trying do something with first example from here 
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.2/tutorial-data-sources.html

and overwrite data1 but if my_data is variable sent by my form...

```
data1 = request.POST["my_data"];
```

I can't access data from POST like this (JS it's client not server side, yea?)

```
data1 = {{ my_data }};
```

this way would be possible inside Django template, not inside `<script> </script>` block

There is another way except putting "Load data" button with Ajax request for data in POST['my_data'] ? I am just starting with Django and I don't have idea what should I do? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, the easiest (but not the most flexible and secure) solution would be to render the js variables just in the Django template:

Assuming your context var `my_data` contains the data needed for the Handsontable, put this in `your_template.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = "{{ my_data }}";
    // now your data is on the JS side.
</script>
```

Comment: But can I flexibly get my_data value in javascript (my_value is POST variable in python) if JS script would be inside django template just like that? And if a have table in python I have to save it to as JSON and parse in JS side, I'm right?

Comment: Right, you just put the initialization script inside your django template. The other way (recommended by AngularJS folks) is to make an AJAX request after loading your page, but it seems to be an overkill in your case. The way you store you data doesn't matter, as long as you can transform it to JSON and feed it to your JS.

Comment: I had few more problems, so I will write it in the comment for others:  if you have data using unicode (what is very common in django), don't forget "escapejs" -> var to_parse = "{{ my_data | escapejs }}". It resolves many problems. Thx for help!